# How to deploy connected App

Tags: connected-apps, client-id

I have created a Connected app in source Org for Tooling API  when I am trying to deploy connected App to target org using Gearset....deployment is to going to success but functionality is not working. **Our requirement is that connected App should be created automatically in target org.**

Answer (score 2):

The Connected App will be created automatically when it is first used in that org. There is no need to deploy a Connected App to multiple orgs.

Comment: Pls, can u suggest what about Name credential and  Oauth provider which is created in Source org...if I will do not deploy the connected app...?